# Error while building Passthrough stream First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found alerts

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

**Scenario**
I've created a proxy service which calls an endpoint. The endpoints gives XML response. I'm using Foreach Mediator to iterate through the XML response using the defined XPath expression. Finally, each record will be inserted to the database using the DB Report Mediator.

**Proxy Service**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="alertsIoscoProxy" startOnLoad="true" statistics="enable" trace="enable" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="https://www.XXXXXX/investor_protection/investor_alerts/xml-feed">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </address>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <foreach expression="//alerts/alert" id="foreach_alert">
                <sequence>
                    <dbreport>
                        <connection>
                            <pool>
                                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</url>
                                <user>postgres</user>
                                <password>admin</password>
                            </pool>
                        </connection>
                        <statement>
                            <sql><![CDATA[insert into IOSCO_RESPONSE (ID, DATE_POSTED, COMPANY,REGULATOR, JURISDICTION, LINK, SUBJECT) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]]></sql>
                            <parameter expression="//id" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                            <parameter expression="//datePosted" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                            <parameter expression="//company" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                            <parameter expression="//regulator" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                            <parameter expression="//jurisdiction" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                            <parameter expression="//link" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                            <parameter expression="//subject" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                        </statement>
                    </dbreport>
                </sequence>
            </foreach>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="add" value="Records added!!!!"/>
            </log>
            <sequence key="Lookup"/>
            <respond/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

**Sample XML**

```
<alerts>
    <message>Results are capped at 500 records.</message>
    <alert>
        <id>23091</id>
        <datePosted>20221209</datePosted>
        <company>Trado Banco</company>
        <regulator>Financial Conduct Authority</regulator>
        <jurisdiction>United Kingdom</jurisdiction>
        <link>https://www.fca.org.uk/news/warnings/trado-banco</link>
        <subject>Regarding fraudulent or manipulative practices (insider dealing, market manipulation, misrepresentation of material information, etc.)<br /><br />Regarding registration of issuance, offer or sale of securities/derivatives, and reporting requirements<br /><br />Regarding market intermediaries (investment and trading advisers, collective investment schemes, brokers, dealers, and transfer agents)<br /><br />Regarding markets, exchanges, and clearing and settlement entities<br /><br />Miscellaneous</subject>
        <comments/>
        <attachments/>
    </alert>
.
.
.

</alerts>
```

**Error**

```
[2022-12-13 23:42:55,323]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - {proxy:alertsIoscoProxy} Proxy Service alertsIoscoProxy received a new message...
[2022-12-13 23:42:55,323]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - {proxy:alertsIoscoProxy} Message To: null
[2022-12-13 23:42:55,323]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - {proxy:alertsIoscoProxy} SOAPAction: null
[2022-12-13 23:42:55,323]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - {proxy:alertsIoscoProxy} WSA-Action: null
[2022-12-13 23:42:55,324]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - Setting specified anonymous fault-sequence for proxy
[2022-12-13 23:42:55,324]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - {proxy:alertsIoscoProxy} Using the anonymous in-sequence of the proxy service for mediation
[2022-12-13 23:42:55,878]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - Setting specified anonymous fault-sequence for proxy
[2022-12-13 23:42:57,175] ERROR {RelayUtils} - Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found alerts
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.constructNode(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:305)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:252)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createNextOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:234)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:249)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createStAXSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:73)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:79)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:196)
        at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:65)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:153)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.util.PassThroughMessageHandler.buildMessage(PassThroughMessageHandler.java:103)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:155)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:96)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:72)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:377)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:627)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:208)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:298)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**Question**

Why proxy Service is considering the response as Soap while its HTTP response with xml based formatting? How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Which product/version are you using?

Comment: Im using wso2mi-4.1.0 for deployment and latest integration studio

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this issue is, your response coming from `https://www.XXXXXX/investor_protection/investor_alerts/xml-feed` maybe having the Content-Type set to `text/xml` which is by default considered as a SOAP message and built with the `SOAPMessageBuilder`. If you can change the backend to send `application/xml` as the content type this would resolve the issue. Else you will have to change the [Message Builder](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/setup/message_builders_formatters/message-builders-and-formatters/#!) configurations to build `text/xml` messages with `ApplicationXMLBuilder`. For that you need to add the following to the deployment.toml.

```ini
[[custom_message_builders]]
content_type = "text/xml"
class="org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder"
```

Note that this will affect all the SOAP 1.1 calls as well, which use `text/xml` content type. To avoid this you can create a custom message builder as well. More details are on the aforementioned doc.

Comment: I've used the property <property name="ContentType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/> before response but it didnt solved my issue

Comment: @AyubJamal What's is the response content type you receive from the backend?